# Get query string from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have been trying fetching the `query string` from url using javascript.

I am using following code

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    prodId = getParameterByName('id');
    prodName = getParameterByName('name');
});
```

It works well for URL like `http://my_ip/main.html?id=123&name=test`

But when URL is like `http://192.168.0.216:1009/main.html#!/video.html?id=123&name=test` it fails, giving empty string for `prodID` and `prodName`

Comment: Work for me. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/79bfja9e/)

Comment: The query string has to be before the hash. The URL should be `http://192.168.0.216:1009/main.html?id=123&name=test#!/video.html`

Comment: @Barmar Probably OP uses some SPA framework where query string is emulated like this.

Comment: He probably need to URL-encode the `#` if it's intended to be part of the pathname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `http://192.168.0.216:1009/main.html#!/video.html?id=123&name=test` doesn't have `location.search` part. It has `location.hash` - everything after `#` character.

The simple thing you can do is to modify the function to be able to work with location.hash too. For example like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, useHash) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location[useHash ? 'hash' : 'search']);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var prodId = getParameterByName('id', true); // true - use location.hash for "query parameters"
```